# Sturm-Liouville result

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

Suppose $n \ge 2$ an integer and consider finding the first eigenvalue of
$$ -\partial_\theta \left( \omega(\theta) \psi'(\theta) \right) = \mu_1 \omega(\theta) \psi(\theta)$$ for $ 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{4}$  with $ \psi'(0)=\psi'( \frac{\pi}{4})=0$ and we want $ \psi'>0$.     Of course the first eigenvalue is zero but we want the first with a nonconstant eigenfunction.

In the case of $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ one can explicitly compute the first eigenpair and the first eigenvalue is (i believe) $4n$.  Additionally using Sturm-Liouville theory (and reflecting across $ \frac{\pi}{4}$) one can see this eigenvalue we are looking is maybe the third eigenvalue on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2}$).

Question.  So I am interested in whether there is some trivial formula for the eigenvalue I am looking for (and I just can't see it or..).

thanks for all replies.

EDIT. We are taking  $\omega(\theta):=\cos^{n-1}(\theta) \sin^{n-1}(\theta)$.   Also I am taking $ \mu_1$ to be the first non trivial eigenvalue.  I guess I should really just say $ \mu_2$.

EDIT 2 (Really a long comment).
thanks for the comments.  Let me explain where this is coming from.   In another problem I had $ \omega(\theta) = \cos^{m-1}(\theta) \sin^{n-1}(\theta)$ and I was working on $ (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ with the Neumann BC.    Here $m,n \ge 1$ integers.  By playing around with the problem I realized there was an explicit (and easy) first nontrival eigenpair.   Now I am taking $m=n$ and reducing it to $( 0 , \frac{\pi}{4})$  and I don't see some nice easy formula.  I can see by extending across $ \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ this is really maybe the third or so eigenvalue of the full problem on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Edit 3. (sorry for all the edits).  In the above example with $N=m+n$ on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ I believe one has

$$ \mu_1=2N, \quad \psi_1(\theta)= \frac{m-n}{N} - \cos(2 \theta).$$

Comment: Maybe it's obvious for the other viewers but it isn't for me: what is your operator? Is it $\psi\mapsto-(\omega\psi')'/\omega$? Or does it act on $\omega$? Is $n$ the dimension? What is $\omega$, a smooth function? You're asking for the eigenvalue of an equality, is $\mu_1$ a notation for your eigenvalue? For me, your question is very difficult to read, and requires a few more precisely stated “Let ... be ...”.

Comment: I knew I wrote a sloppy question but I didn't realize it was this bad.  Let me go edit it a bit.

Comment: @PierrePC: Yes, that would be the standard operator associated with this SL equation. It acts on $L^2(\omega\, dx)$.

Comment: So normally one would insist that $\omega > 0$ ...

Comment: I was convinced there was no simple little formula but I made a mistake.  After looking for solutions of the form $ \psi(\theta)= A - \cos(4 \theta)$ I believe there is a simple solution.   So I guess I should close the question.  Thanks for all the comments.